# No Service Workers with Avahi/Zeroconf (machineName.local)

Tags: javascript, service-worker, zeroconf, avahi

When testing for [service worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) capability in the browser:

(in `index.html`)

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('serviceWorker OK');
} else {
    console.log('serviceWorker NOT OK');
}
```

Now if I call `localhost/index.html` I get a positive result:

=> serviceWorker OK

Same when using loopback (`127.0.0.1/index.html`).

Now if I call `mymachine.local/index.html` suddenly the capability diseappears:

=> serviceWorker NOT OK

Is it an [Avahi](http://avahi.org)/Zeroconf restriction, or just a problem with my OS implementation?

Comment: Service workers only run over HTTPS, for security reasons. During development you'll be able to use service worker through localhost, but to deploy it on a site you'll need to have HTTPS setup on your server.

Comment: You can get HTTPS working on your local development environment.